# Need to get the toplevel widget from an XtAppContext

Tags: x11, motif

I'm looking for something like `XtWidgetToApplicationContext()` however that would work the *other* way around ↔ return the toplevel **widget** from its **application context**. Is there such function? In general, how to obtain the widget from owning application context?